# How to remove blog name from page title in individual blog posts?

Tags: blogger

Currently on my blog (which is hosted on Blogger `*.blogspot.com`) the title shown on the window/tab of browser appears as:

> [Blog Name]: [Blog Post Title]

I would like to remove `[Blog Name]` from title so that it only appears as:

> [Blog Post Title]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.   Edit your template, and find this code:

> `<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>`

Replace it with

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
  <title>
    <data:blog.pageName/> </title>
  <b:else/>
  <title>
    <data:blog.pageTitle/>
  </title>
</b:if>
```

An alternative code if you want to display the blog title after the post title (in [Page name] | [Blog title] format)

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
  <title>
    <data:blog.pageName/> |
    <data:blog.title/>
  </title> <b:else/>
  <title>
    <data:blog.pageTitle/>
  </title>
</b:if>
```

Comment: This has worked brilliantly for my blog posts. How can I do the same for static pages?